# How to set the appropriate http headers for gzip

Tags: node.js, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I'm using Unity's WebGL and I'm getting this message on the console **"You can reduce your startup time if you configure your web server to host .unityweb files using gzip compression."** So according to Unity's documentation, I need to add the correct response Headers https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-deploying.html.

I found the "express-static-gzip" module, and I tried to do just that, but the warning is still there. Below is the server.

[image]

```
const express = require('express');
const ip = require("ip");
const expressStaticGzip = require('express-static-gzip');
const http = require('http');


const app = express();
const server = http.Server(app);

app.use('/public/Builds/Build/', expressStaticGzip('public/Builds/Build/', {
    customCompressions: [{
        encodingName: "gzip",
        fileExtension: "unityweb"
    }]
}));


// app.use(compression());
app.use(express.static('public'));

server.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log( ":: http://" + ip.address() + "/ ::" );
});
```

Any ideas?
Nick

Answer (score 3):

Many thanks to @d_shiv for his help. I changed the code to the following, and the warning went away.

(you can change gzip with br if you're using brotli)

```
const express = require('express');
const ip = require("ip");
const http = require('http');


const app = express();
const server = http.Server(app);

app.use(express.static('public', {
    setHeaders: function(res, path) {
        if(path.endsWith(".unityweb")){
            res.set("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
        }
    }
}));

server.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log( ":: http://" + ip.address() + ":3000/ ::" );
});
```

Comment: hi
i missed something if you may, where and how did you place this code? did you update an existing JS file? (which one?) or added this file to the project/build files (where?)

Comment: This is for the nodejs server.

Answer (score 1):

`express-static-gzip` does not gzip the files on the fly before serving it. It assumes that you have the normal as well as gzipped versions of the file available on the specified directory. Check the [Examples section of documentation here](https://github.com/tkoenig89/express-static-gzip#example).

In this scenario, if the `public/Builds/Build/Builds.wasm.framework.unityweb` had to be transferred with gzip compression, you'd need to create a gzipped version by name of `public/Builds/Build/Builds.wasm.framework.unityweb.gz`. The middleware will automatically scan the folder for all such file pairs where original as well as gzipped versions are available. It will serve the gzipped version when request comes for original file, if the browser supports it.

The `customCompressions` array should also be skipped since that's enabled by default. The middleware would be registered, something like this:

```
app.use('/Builds/Build/', expressStaticGzip('public/Builds/Build/'));
```

Also note that `public/` is removed from the middleware path (should be present in the `expressStaticGzip` path though). This is because your assets are being loaded from path `https://{hostname}/Builds/Build/...`.

If you intend to compress the files on the fly and server it, take a look at [compression](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression) module. The can be very costly operation for your server though, if possible do the gzipping during build time to create the equivalent `.gz` files, and continue to use `express-static-gzip`.

Comment: many thanks for the reply @d_shiv!

In my case, the Builds.wasm.framework.unityweb is already gzipped by Unity and according to the instructions from Unity, the server just needs to add the gzip, deflate encode to the header so the browser can unzip it, otherwise, unity uses JS to unzip it which is slow.

Do you know how I can make the server to add the correct headers to the already zipped static files with extension unityweb?

Comment: Ahh, alright. Since the original file itself is gzipped, I am not sure if the express-static-gzip will work for you. But regardless, first try to remove the leading `/public` from middleware path (first param to `app.use`), leaving the original options as is. If the module can handle gzipped files alone even without the original, this might work.

Comment: As per code it wouldn't work. Check https://github.com/tkoenig89/express-static-gzip/blob/master/index.js#L154. The middleware expects the request to come at path excluding the `fileExtension` that is provided. So the gzipped  `Builds.wasm.framework.unityweb` will be sent if request came for `Builds.wasm.framework` without the `.unityweb` extension. If you want to use this module, may be add a build step to rename these files and add `.gz` extension. Or skip this completely, and add a custom middleware instead which checks if `req.path` ends with `.unityweb` and adds right header to response.